# If there isn't a keyboard input for a set amount of time skip needing input

Tags: c++, keyboard, skip, getch

I am trying to get a keyboard input, but if it doesn't happen in about half a second I want it to continue to the rest of the loop. I tried using kbhit(); but it won't wait for the input, it just loops with out stopping. This is the loop in question:

```
    while(flags)
{
    gameing.updateDraw(0, 0);
    keyIn = getch();
    //Sleep(20);
    switch(keyIn)
    {
        case UP_ARROW:
                flags = gameing.updateDraw(-1, 1);
                break;
        case DOWN_ARROW:
                flags = gameing.updateDraw(1, 1);
                break;
        case WKEY:
                flags = gameing.updateDraw(-1, 2);
                break;
        case SKEY:
                flags = gameing.updateDraw(1, 2);
                break;
    }
```

All help will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to avoid using alarm();

Answer (score 0):

The comnented call to `Sleep` indicates that this is a Windows program using `<conio.h>` functionality, and not a *nix program using curses.

With `<conio.h>` you can use the `kbhit` function to check whether there is a keypress.

Place that in a loop that sleeps a little bit between each call.

More advanced you can use the Windows API. Its wait functions can wait on a console handle, with a specified timeout.

The C++ standard library does not have unbuffered keyboard input functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured a good way to do it with kbhit

        while(flags)
    {
        keyIn = 0;
        gameing.updateDraw(0, 0);
        Sleep(100);
        if(_kbhit())
        
The time was too much work compared to this, and as for Alf's answer I interpreted your answer as just using kbhit instead of getch(), and kbhit only returns that a key was pressed and not what key was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like ctime.h or chrono to get the time difference. Then do something like

```
long lastTime=CurrentTime();
int input=0;
while(!(input=kbhit()) && CurrentTime()-lastTime < 20);
if(input)
    // do stuff with input
// do all the other stuff
lastTime=CurrentTime();
```

Disclaimer. I'm not particularly familiar with kbhit and things, but based on a little bit of googling, this seems like it ought to work. Also the implementation of CurrentTime is up to you, it doesn't have to be a long or anything, I just chose that for simplicity's sake.